# Can C++11 decltype be used to create a typedef for function pointer from an existing function?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

Given

```
struct A { 
    int foo(double a, std::string& b) const;
};
```

I can create a member function pointer like this:

```
typedef int (A::*PFN_FOO)(double, std::string&) const;
```

Easy enough, except that `PFN_FOO` needs to be updated if `A::foo`'s signature changes. Since C++11 introduces `decltype`, could it be used to automatically deduce the signature and create the typedef?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes, of course:

`typedef decltype(&A::foo) PFN_FOO;`

You can also define type alias via [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) keyword (Thanks to Matthieu M.):

`using PFN_FOO = decltype(&A::foo);`

Comment: +1 for answer, but wish I could give -1 for beating me to it by 30 seconds! :p

Comment: Of course ;-) But is this just in theory? I can't get it to compile (http://ideone.com/lXDLpL).

Comment: Sorry, be quick or be... without rep :-)

Comment: @DanielGehriger No, see updated answer with proof. Looks like ideone has outdated GCC version. On 4.7.1 it's OK.

Comment: @Daniel: You forgot the `;` after the definition of `A`.

Comment: Works for me in Visual Studio 2012 too.

Comment: @Xeo - ouch. First time in 20 years. Oh well.

Comment: You might as well go C++11 all the way: `using PFN_FOO = decltype(&A::foo);`

Comment: Note that this *will not work* if `A::foo` is overloaded, because you need to do an explicit cast to the proper type.

Comment: @NicolBolas OP doesn't mentioned about overloads, but Matthieu M. already covered this in his answer.

Answer (score 24):

One issue: you may only deduce the type of a variable if this variable is unambiguous.

The main issue with functions is that *overloads* mean that their names alone are insufficient to identify them. Therefore using `decltype` fails should you ever introduce an overload of `foo` in `A`.

```
struct A {
    void foo() const;
    void foo(int) const;
};

using PFN_FOO = decltype(A::foo);
```

> ```
> source.cpp:6:36: error: decltype cannot resolve address of overloaded function
> ```

Not sure you'll be gaining much thus...

On the other hand, you can actually use an alias *and check that alias is right*:

```
struct A {
    void foo() const;
    void foo(int) const;
};

using PFN_FOO = void (A::*)(int) const;

static_assert(std::is_same<PFN_FOO, decltype(static_cast<PFN_FOO>(&A::foo))>::value,
     "Ooops, need to update signature of PFN_FOO!");
```

*Note: not sure this is the best way to test, basically all you need is the `static_cast` part, I just wanted to stash an error message alongside. You would probably need something like SFINAE to get better messages though.*

Comment: Mathieu: thanks - yes, I also realized this becuase I was trying to get rid of complex typedefs which are needed precisely for overload resolution. I like your static_assert though!