# Typedef an already defined function

Tags: c++, c

I'm implementing some low level stuff and need to "typedef" many system (Windows) functions. For example, this is a test function that I want to typedef for the hook:

```
BOOL WINAPI WindowsFunction(Param1: DWORD, Param2:DWORD, Param3:DWORD);
```

And the Typedef should be:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *TWindowsFunction)(Param1: DWORD, Param2:DWORD, Param3:DWORD);
```

This is OK for a few functions, but if I want to do the above for dozens of functions, is there a shortcut (like a "magic #define") that will save me from copying almost the exact function declaration over and over again? A "magic" like:

```
#define TYPEDEF_FUNCTION(WindowsFunction....)
```

Thanks!

Comment: 1) That's not valid C syntax. 2) Why do you need all those typedefs?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and redefine the problem

Comment: That's not valid C++ syntax, there is no ':' between the type and the parameter name.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed Pascal with C! :(

Comment: Removed C tag as accepted answer, what OP wanted, is not applicable to C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11's `decltype` [can be used this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089227/364696), either with `typedef` or `using`:

```
typedef decltype(&WindowsFunction) TWindowsFunction;
```

or:

```
using TWindowsFunction = decltype(&WindowsFunction);
```

Comment: Wow! That's what I'm talking about! Thanks a lot. You made my day :)